# Batch insert with data having special char not working with postgres jsonb column

Tags: java, jdbc, jsonb, batch-insert

I am trying to perform batch insert into postgres column of type jsonb using jdbc. The data I am trying to insert has special char like '.

My query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO myschema.EMP( PAYLOAD) VALUES (cast(:payload as json))
```

My payload looks like, after converting string to json in java (Java API escaped single quote present in the payload with the back-slash):

```
'{"name": "Sahil", "desc": "Working as\'s a developer"}'
```

Whenever I am trying to perform batch-insert using jdbc, it fails as cast function not able to escape back slash in the payload.
Then I tried using E to escape backslash.

```
INSERT INTO myschema.EMP( PAYLOAD) VALUES (cast(E:payload as json))
```

After this, JDBC not able to bind the payload variable value.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and expand on what you mean with _"After this, JDBC not able to bind the payload variable value."_ (Do you get an error? If so, what is that error?)

Comment: @Mark: in simple words, how can we insert above mentioned payload in the table using jdbc, database is Postgres and column is of type jsonb.